# Powershell: How to silently run an Outlook 2010 Rule?

Tags: .net, powershell, outlook, outlook-2010

I would like to make a Powershell script that runs an Outlook2010 rule.  The same question was asked at the below URL; however, there was no solution at the time.

[social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/b0457f49-d895-48c7-a36f-d1f3ce6e18e6/how-to-run-the-server-side-existing-rule-in-exchange-2010?forum=exchangesvrclients&prof=required)

If there's a way to do this in C# or VBScript, I dont mind going that route; as long as there's some kind of feasible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server-side rules are applied to messages before they are delivered.

If I had to do this, I'd use Powershell and the EWS managed API, and script going through the Inbox items and emulating whatever that rule does with the email.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not very experienced with C# coding yet.  Could you be a bit more specific on how on how to do this?  The API seems to desbribe basic rule manipulation: listing, creating, modifying, and deleting rules (which I can already do via the microsoft.office.interop.outlook assembly).  If someone could please help me get started, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Have a look at some of the examples on Glen Scales blog: http://gsexdev.blogspot.com

Comment: I already did when searching via google earlier today. I didn't see any examples in that blog showing how to run a rule; especially via powershell... It seems like all the example I see show how create, modify, remove rules. not actually run them.

Comment: You can't "run the rule".  You have to reproduce (in your script) whatever it was the rule would have done.